# Changing printf() to print() safely?

Tags: php, printing, printf, echo

So I for some reason or another adopted using `printf()` as a replacement for `echo` or `print`

I don't have any formatted strings that REQUIRE `printf($var);`, so they could (and should) all be turned into `print($var);`

Since they've all got the same syntax `printf($this.'that');` could I just do a folder-wide "find & replace" to change `printf(` to `print(` safely?

Comment: Sure, why not? Best is to use a regex based modifying tool. Check `kfilereplace`, served me uncounted times...

Comment: Because things do break. Not "often" but when something does stop working, I replace `printf` with `print` or `echo` and it usually works, if that's the issue. So it 'works' I just want it to be more stable

Comment: `so they could (and should) all be turned into print($var);` [citation needed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have calls to `printf` that do not expect formatting, you are going to run into problems and they really should be changed to `print`. For example, if your input to `printf` contains the `%` character, you will get an error instead about having a badly formatted argument string.

```
$something = 'Results: 10% complete.';
print($something);
printf($something); // ERROR: printf() thinks it should replace "% c"
                    //        with an integer not passed as a second argument
printf('%s',$something); // Pass unquoted input as a formatted argument
```

So basically, if your code has never used `printf` with consciously formatted input, you would benefit from a find/replace in your code to convert all those calls to `print`.

Comment: thanks for the nice clarification! I'd be curious to see if the few errors I did get were because of a `%` in the string... Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! And probably so: It's very easy for unquoted input to have odd side effects like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you don't use printf functionality anywhere, and print is sufficient, than yes, you can replace it all with a simple search/replace.